# Displaying different numbers on 7 Segment

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, hdl

I'm using Digilent Basys 3 board. It has 4 x 7 Segment displays. Currently my codes are

```
module segmentdisplay(input clk,
                      output segA, segB, segC, segD, segE, segF, segG, segDP,D1,D2,D3,D4
);


assign D1 = 1'b1; //to switch off the Right most 7 segment display

assign {segA, segB, segC, segD, segE, segF, segG, segDP} = 8'b00100100;   // light the leds to display '2'

endmodule
```

as of now, all my three 7 segments are showing the digit '2'.

I understand that that all 4 7segments are tied to the same a,b,c,d,e,f,g

How to i make them show '1' '2' '3' at the sametime? Thanks guys.

Comment: Typically, the cathode pins are connected to the segment bits and the anode pins are connected to `D1...D4`. You need to implement a time multiplexing algorithm which switches the segment bits accordingly to the one-hot encoded anode pins.

Answer (score 0):

7 segment display works with 4 input at D1 to D4, and you are right, all 4 displays uses the same a to g.

The trick is to set up the display such that only one 7 segment display lights up and shows the number at any point in time. However, the duration that the code switches to the next display to show the next number should be very small.

What it essentially mean is that at such a fast rate of switching between D1 to D4, and while each display shows a different number, our eyes are tricked into thinking that the displays is actually showing a few numbers at once (or in your case 3).

Since you only want to display a 3 digit number, the code should only alternate between D2 to D4, with their respective input for the digit to be displayed.